# why does setting an image background overrides bootstrap buttons' background color?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Why does this CSS override bootstrap button background styling and makes it transparent rather than the default button of the color?

For example, if I have a button and I have the styling below in my document which sets the `background-image` of the whole body to an image. I can see that it overrides the background of the buttons as well and makes the same color as the image. is there a reason why does that happen and how to fix it?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url('assets/background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button class="btn btn-warning m-4">A Button</button>
```

Comment: Why would you possibly apply those styles to every element in your document?

Comment: Do you know what `*` means in CSS?

Comment: Also, I think you're mistaken. See the demo above.

Comment: It sets background image to all elements of your page, not just for `<body>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is using **`*`** selector, This selector is used to select all the elements in your document (In your case * selects => html tag, body tag, and button tag)

If u wish to give background image to body use **`body`**  saelector instead of **`*`**

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1676269098733-4a94f912d838?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button class="btn btn-warning m-4">A Button</button>
```